# External App License for Scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, userlicense, scratch-org-definition-file

Deploying profiles to Scratch Org, got error **userLicense - no UserLicense named External Apps** found because I don't have **External App** license on scratch org. Can't find how to create with this license, or run it on in existing. Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Add "COMMUNITIES" in the Definition file under "FEATURES" before creating the scratch org and the org will have all the licenses related to the Experience cloud.

```
"features": ["Communities"],
```